# How I can filter a xml file to a attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, arraylist, linq-to-xml

hi I want filter a xml file to a attribute.

Here my xml:

```
<plants>
  <plant id="DB" display=".testDB.." group="NPS_DB" />
  <plant id="EL" display=".testEL.." group="NPS_EL" />
  <plant id="IN" display="..testIN." group="NPS_IN" />
  <plant id="SB" display=".testSB.." group="NPS_SB" />
  <plant id="BL" display=".testBL.." group="NPS_BL" />
  <plant id="LS" display="..testLS.." group="NPS_LS" />
</plants>
```

here my code:

```
ArrayList ActiveUserList = myclass.GetGroupmemberList(Domain, Username);    
XDocument x = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\location.xml"));       
int index = ActiveUserList.Count;        
ArrayList DropDownList = new ArrayList();    
for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
{
      IEnumerable<XElement> list = from el in x.Descendants("group")
                                   where (string)el.Attribute("Type") == ActiveUserList[i].ToString()
                                   select el;

    //Here I want the display attribute value where group = "nps_db" ???        
}
```

For Example my Username is in the group nps_db so i want that i get the display attribute where is group = np_db in arraylist. I want to use this ArrayList for a DropDownList later.

Comment: Your xml above don't have `group` element and `Type` attribute

Comment: your XML and c# code does not match